# Property or method is not defined on the instance but reference. Advice needed

Tags: vue.js

I am tring to print key and value of an object based on state inside the store:
But i am getting this error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "deviceInfo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

What am i doing wrong?

```html
<template>
    <div id="device-details-view">      
         {{deviceinfo['OffenderID']}}   <!--WORKS-->
         {{deviceinfo[Object.keys(deviceinfo)[0]]}}   <!--WORKS-->

       <!--NOR WORKING-->

        <div class="device-info-container" v-for="(field, key, index) in deviceInfo" :key="index">
            <LabelAndData :key="index" :title="key" :data="field"/>
        </div> 
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from "vuex";
import  LabelAndData from "../common/List";

const DeviceAgencyIDTitle='Agency ID'; 
const DeviceOffenderID='OffenderID';
const DeviceSerialNumber='Serial Number';
const DeviceDescription='Description';
const DeviceOffenderNameTitle='Offender Name';

const DeviceInfo = (device) => {
    const deviceDataList =[ {      
        [DeviceSerialNumber]: device.SerialNumber,        
        [DeviceDescription]: device.Description,                 
        [DeviceOffenderID]: device.OffenderID,         
        [DeviceAgencyIDTitle]: device.AgencyID
    }]
}

export default {

  components: {
    LabelAndData
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      currentDevice: 'currentDevice'
    }),
    deviceinfo: function () {
      //return "test";
      //DeviceInfo(this.$store.getters.currentDevice);
      const device = this.$store.getters.currentDevice;
      const deviceDataList = [{
        [DeviceSerialNumber]: device.SerialNumber,
        [DeviceDescription]: device.Description,
        [DeviceOffenderID]: device.OffenderID,
        [DeviceAgencyIDTitle]: device.AgencyID

      }]
      return deviceDataList[0];


    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: what you want to do with this `{  [DeviceSerialNumber]: device.SerialNumbe}`

Comment: Seems obvious, the ones that work use `deviceinfo` (all **lowercase**). The ones that don't work are using `deviceInfo` with a **capital "I"**. Your computed property is `deviceinfo`. **Voting to close as a typo**